# zkemkeeper.dll utilizar la función CaptureImage y GetPhotoByName

Tags: c#, zkemkeeper

Trabajo con un lector biometrico **[ZKTeco Iface 402](https://www.google.com/search?q=ZKTeco+Iface+402&oq=ZKTeco+Iface+402&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.1118j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** para el cual ya pude obtener los marcajes, y los datos usuarios (nombre y numero), pero también me gustaría obtener las **fotos de registro** y las **fotos al momento del marcaje**, busque un poco y  encontré un [pdf guia](https://es.scribd.com/doc/299899749/Sdk-Manual-for-zk-devices-VB-C) que esta en ingles, en el cual dice que la función  `GetPhotoByName` es para las **fotos de registro** y `CaptureImage` para las **fotos al momento del marcaje**, pero al momento de utilizarlos el ide de desarrollo(visual studio2012) me marca error y no compila el codigo, Agradeceria si alguien podria ayudarme a como utilizar estas dos funciones de la libreria zkemkeeper.
Os dejo la parte de codigo donde me sale error:

```
bool FullImage = false;
int Width=new int();
int Height=new int();
byte[] Image=new byte[1024];
string path = path_images;
while (connect.CaptureImage(FullImage,ref Width,ref Height,ref Image, path))
{

}
string PhotoName="";
byte[] PhotoData=new byte[1024];
int Photolength=0;
while (connect.GetPhotoByName(id_biometric, PhotoName, out PhotoData, out Photolength)) { 

}
```

Los errores son los mismos en ambos `while`s

> the best overloaded method macth for 'funcion que utilizo' has some invalid argument

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El guia dice que las funciones estan declaradas de la siguiente forma:

```
VARIANT_BOOL getPhotoByName([in]long dwMachineNumber,[in]BSTR PhotoName,[out]Byte *PhotoData,[out]long *PhotoLength)

VARIANT_BOOL CaptureImage([in] VARIANT_BOOL FullImage, [in] LONG *Width,[in]LONG *Height,[in]BYTE *Image,[in] BSTR ImageFile)
```

Cabe aclarar que todo lo que es ´long´ en la declaraciones los puse como `int` porque mi ide de trabajo los reconoce como `int` ademas de que igual ya intente con `long`.

Al notar que nadie ve el link de la guia lo vuelvo a poner [**aqui**](https://es.scribd.com/doc/299899749/Sdk-Manual-for-zk-devices-VB-C)

Comment: Claramente el error es que o te faltan parametros o no le estas pasando los tipos de datos correctos. Para poder sabe eso necesitamos alguna informacion de la libreria como la documentacion

Comment: deje el link de la [guia pdf](https://es.scribd.com/doc/299899749/Sdk-Manual-for-zk-devices-VB-C) en la pregunta.

Comment: Te da error porque le estás pasando un array de bytes (byte[] Image y byte[] PhotoData) cuando le tienes que pasar un byte, con eso solucionas la llamada al método.

Answer (score 1):

Edito viendo tu comentario. Los `*` parecen referirse a punteros "crudos". Por lo que quizás debas declarar tus variables de esa forma:

```
Byte *PhotoData;
long *PhotoLength;
```

En tal caso, PhotoLength podría ser un simple `long`y PhotoData un array de byte al que podrás acceder así:

### Pseudocódigo:

```
for(int i=0; i<PhotoLength; i++)
{
     Console.Write(PhotoData[i]); //ya podemos acceder a cada elemento 
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: id_biometric es `int`, y ya me ayudo con la conexión de mi pc al lector biometrico, ahora en la documentación dice que la función esta definida como: `VARIANT_BOOL getPhotoByName([in]long dwMachineNumber,[in]BSTR PhotoName,[out]Byte *PhotoData,[out] *PhotoLength)`, lo que no entiendo muy bien es los **(*)** asteriscos. Al igual la otra funcion esta declarada como: `VARIANT_BOOL CaptureImage([in] VARIANT_BOOL FullImage, [in] LONG *Width,[in] *Height,[in]BYTE *Image,[in] BSTR ImageFile)`, y de la misma forma los asteriscos son los problemas "creo".

Comment: Edito la respuesta puesto que la anterior no resolvió tu problema, y te propongo una nueva solución.

Comment: ¿A que otra respuesta te refieres?